# Mathematica Issue

Tags: piecewise

I'm completely new to Mathematica, and I'm facing an issue.

[image]

So basically, I know that Out[43]'s answer is 1+2a+3b. And out[44] is a+b. I dont know why it's giving me a different answer here. Can anyone help? Thank you!!

Comment: You need to leave space between a constant and a variable, i.e you should write `a x` and not `ax`

Comment: What @kcr said, but in addition: use `*` instead of a space unless you have a very good reason to omit it.

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title... one that describes the body of your question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Mathematica sees ax as a single, different variable, separate from a and x.  That's why you're seeing the result you get.  As kcr said, separate the letters to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your function has two different polynomial forms for different ranges of $x$, meeting at $x=1$.  Thus if you take the derivative at that point $x=1$, it will have one value if you come from $x>1$, and a different value if you come from $x<1$.